# Laravel chat channel authentication without full user instance

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, chat

Authentication: I want to build a anonymous chat which people with the channelname and password can access.

Remember instance: When they enter the correct channel/pass-combination, they will be assigned a random username. Their messages will be linked to this username.

The only way I know how to authenticate people is through the user instance, but for convenience and anonimity I don't want people to create a whole account. I wish to use the User class for people to create new chat channels with.

So the architecture is like this:

User hasMany Chat hasMany AnonUser hasMany Message

Can someone explain how to authenticate anonymous users through a channel/pass-combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not mention your version of Laravel.. in case you did I would send you a sample code, but anyway here is the link to the most recent version's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

you can find all the neccassary information there.

best

Comment: I solved the problem by using a different architecture, thanks anyway! User hasmany Groups hasmany Messages, and to each message there is a Ghost instance which is saved in the session of unauthenticated users. I'm going to accept this answer to remove the open question.